# Cant draw a line in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I want to draw a line of 2 pixels..I have written the following code but it does not draw any line or anything on the view..Plzz help me regarding this or tell me the error in this code...In code *pointToBeShown* is *CGPoint*.....

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.    
CGContextRef context =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();      
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);    
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);         
pointToBeShown.x = 30;  
pointToBeShown.y = 449;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pointToBeShown.x, pointToBeShown.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (pointToBeShown.x + 1),( pointToBeShown.y + 1));
CGContextStrokePath(context); 
}
```

Comment: Is your code actually being called?

Comment: And is your Color different from the background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not getting any warning?

Replace the line

```
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
```

with

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
```

**Update**:
Update as you mentioned in the comments

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[currentColor set];
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(pointToBeShown.x, pointToBeShown.y, 10, 10));
```

Comment: I assume your `currenColor` differs from background color and you are calling this method properly.

Comment: I just want to show the red color point ....so how can i show just a wide point on iphone....

Comment: Increase the line width. Also increase some more x and y values to `pointToBeShown`

Comment: Can i show s single point....as i dont want to show line....what can i write in place of secondlast and thirdlast lines????